# Recommendation on using solver method

Tags: c#, solver

I would like to use a non linear solver to build a model ; attached picture explains the setup that I have.

Each of the P's (P1 to P4) has a list of " (tau and f's) which need to be solved by the solver.

The constraints are such that "sum of f1 and f2 and f3 respectively etc." for each P's should be <=1.

Any help is highly appreciated. I am totally lost here! [image]

Added a new image. 
"M"column is calculated by using "B6:G6" and "C17:G17". The Qerror is based on H17 and M17. 
i.e. I need to minimize that error by changing "B6:G6" for P1. Similarly I do it for P2 and so on. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgblG.png)

Comment: I tried using MS solver foundation first and failed miserably. It's beyond my understanding (OML). So, I guess I need some other method.

Comment: Understand that sum(f[1..5]j must be <=1, but where does tau come into play?

Comment: And what are the values in the row with "constraints"?  I see that they are the sum of the values above, but are they constrained as well?

Comment: @ClayVerValen: hello Clay.. Regarding your first question, it's sum(f[1..4])j<=1 ; column sum.  Tau and f values are used in a formula (that makes it non linear).  I don't follow your second question, those are the only four constraints in my system

Comment: Solver takes a goal value (min, max, or specific value) and then solves within the constraints.  sum(f1..5) <=1.  From what you've given in your question, all the values in blue could be set to 0.2 and you're done.  But I suspect it is not that simple. To get any help you're going to give more info (e.g. the formula, the goal, do all the columns have to sum to 1, etc.)

Comment: @ClayVerValen: Updated Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update provides a little more clarity on what your problem is. However, I am still making a few assumptions ...

- I think you have 114 rows of data /calculations similar to row 17.
- The calculation of qError is still a bit of a mystery. I think it's something like (for I6) `=sum(M17:M130) - sum(H17:H130)` in order to take into account all 114 data points.
- The calculation of the objective (I11) appears to be `=AVG(I6:I9)`.

If my assumptions are mostly correct, I would make the following modifications and Solver set up:

1. Change qError calculation to qError^2. This would involve adding a column to calculate the squared error for each data point. If this were column Q, the calculation for Q17 would be `=(M17-H17)^2` and this would be filled down. Then, the calculation in I6 would be `=SUM(Q17:Q130)`. Similar columns and calculations would be needed for I7,8, and 9.
2. Keep the calculation of I11 as is, but with the previous change it is now SUM(e^2).

In the solver dialog

1. "Set Objective" is cell `$I$11`.
2. "To:" is Min.
3. "By Changing Variable Cells:" is `$B$6:$G$9`
4. "Subject to the Constraints:" is `$C$11 <= 1`, `$D$11 <= 1`, `$E$11 <= 1`, `$F$11 <= 1`, `$G$11 <= 1`
5. Check "Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative"
6. "Select Solving Method:" is "GRG Nonlinear"

If solver doesn't find a solution, you will probably need to adjust the "Options". Because you have a large number of parameters, the number of allowed iterations will likely need to be increased.

Let me know if I significantly erred on my assumptions.

Comment: Thanks ! Excel solver module does it well to solve it. If I would like to use this in C# (code behind) using Ms Solver foundation, any ideas for that?

Comment: Or any solver method that can be used in C# without having it to go into EXCEL sheet

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer. You should build your program, and ask a new question tagged with C#.